# how to find last transactions all databases with query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT distinct
(sson.login_name) AS USER__NAME
, sson.host_name AS PC__NAME
, sqltxt.text AS CODE__
, conn.session_id AS SID__
, sson.login_time AS LOGIN__TIME
, sson.last_request_start_time AS TRANSACTION_START_TIME
, REQ.total_elapsed_time AS ELAPSED__TIME
, sson.status AS STATUS_
, sson.database_id AS DB__ID
, dbases.name AS DB__NAME
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections conn 
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions sson 
ON conn.session_id = sson.session_id  
INNER JOIN sys.databases dbases
ON sson.database_id=dbases.database_id
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests REQ
ON REQ.session_id=sson.session_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(most_recent_sql_handle) AS sqltxt
```

I used this query. It's work in 2012 and after. But it's not working in sql 2008.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Invalid column name 'database_id'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Invalid column name 'database_id'. 

I think problem is a didnt found database_id inside 'select* from sys.dm_exec_sessions'.

Answer (score 1):

your query for the version > `sql server 2008 r2`  you can try by using below

```
SELECT TOP 1

rsh.destination_database_name AS [Database],

rsh.user_name AS [Restored By],

CASE WHEN rsh.restore_type = 'D' THEN 'Database'

WHEN rsh.restore_type = 'F' THEN 'File'

WHEN rsh.restore_type = 'G' THEN 'Filegroup'

WHEN rsh.restore_type = 'I' THEN 'Differential'

WHEN rsh.restore_type = 'L' THEN 'Log'

WHEN rsh.restore_type = 'V' THEN 'Verifyonly'

WHEN rsh.restore_type = 'R' THEN 'Revert'

ELSE rsh.restore_type

END AS [Restore Type],

rsh.restore_date AS [Restore Started],

bmf.physical_device_name AS [Restored From],

rf.destination_phys_name AS [Restored To]

FROM msdb.dbo.restorehistory rsh

INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset bs ON rsh.backup_set_id = bs.backup_set_id

INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.restorefile rf ON rsh.restore_history_id = rf.restore_history_id

INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bmf ON bmf.media_set_id = bs.media_set_id

where destination_database_name = 'YourDBName'

and restore_type = 'L'

ORDER BY rsh.restore_date DESC
```

[link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f46e80b4-bbb4-4541-ace4-ea92562a4720/how-do-i-identify-last-transaction-log-applied-on-a-standby?forum=sqldisasterrecovery)

Comment: I dont want to applied on a standby. I want to how to find real time transaction with query code. Who is what now like that?